# Adding COUNT in barplot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am  a beginner in R. I am having problem in putting the count in my bar plot.

So my data look like this

```
> head(worker)
  stateur statemb state age tenure    joblost
1     4.5     167    42  49     21      other
2    10.5     251    55  26      2 slack_work
3     7.2     260    21  40     19      other
4      NA     245    56  51     17 slack_work
5     6.5     125    58  33      1 slack_work
6     7.5     188    11  51      3      other
```

I have plot the bar graph by using this code

```
table=table(worker$joblost)
barplot(table, main = "Vertical Bar Plot of the Job Lost")
```

But I want to put the frequency for each category of joblost on top of each bar. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Using `text()`. `barplot()` has an invisible output which you can capture with `<-` and use it for the `x`-positions of the text to add. For `y=` just add the table values plus something that looks good.

```
b <- barplot(tab, beside=TRUE, ylim=c(0, max(tab) + 15), 
             main="Vertical Bar Plot of the Job Lost", col=2:3, border=0)
text(b, tab + 5, tab, font=2, col=2:3)
```

[image]

**Notice** that by using `"table"` as name for your object, you attempt to overwrite the `table()` function! Always check beforehand if the name is free, typing `?table`. If not, use something else.

---

*Data:*

```
tab <- structure(c(other = 56L, slack_work = 44L), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("other", "slack_work")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
```

Comment: Thank you Sir!! Your answer is really helpful for beginner like me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code for that

```
library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(worker,aes(x=factor(joblost)))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge")+ 
  labs(title="Vertical Bar Plot of the Job Lost", x="Job lost", y = "Frequency")+
  geom_text(aes(label=..count..),stat='count',position=position_dodge(0.9),vjust=-0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Given that Izzah is new to R, you should specify that your solution involves using `ggplot2` instead of base R's plotting, and that you need to start with `library(ggplot2)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir!! but unfortunately I am still not familiar with using other R package yet. Later I will explore the package and try using your method.

Comment: @lzzah Just use `install.packages("ggplot2")` once before running the code. It will install `ggplot2` package and next time onwards you have to just call the package by `library(ggplot2)`.